# When are .xlsb files *larger* than .xlsx?

Tags: excel

I know that in general .xlsb files are smaller than .xlsx files. However, I just saved a large .xlsx file as .xlsb (to reduce file size, ironically) and the .xlsb version is significantly larger. For the exact same data, I've gone from 160,188KB (in the .xlsx) to 254,314KB (in the .xlsb).

The file has two tabs. One has 28 columns and ~300,000 rows. Not all the cells in that range are populated, but most are with a variety of text and numeric values (including one long string that takes up ~1,000 characters).

The second tab just has one line of text in a single cell.

There are no formulas, named ranges, pivot tables, or anything like that. I made absolutely no changes to the files, I just opened the .xlsx did a SAVE AS and selected .xlsb.

So I was just really surprised to see the .xlsb so much larger than the .xlsx version, and I wanted to know: what are the general conditions under which this can occur?

Comment: This site is for questions about and issues related to programs or algorithms that you are developing, and not for general purpose computer Q&A. Voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: @PeterB -- I don't disagree with you in concept -- there is no problem to solve, per-se.  That said, I find this a really good question for *somewhere* and I'd genuinely like to know the answer as it's something anyone who uses Excel has to deal with.  Is it better suited for somewhere else in the Stack community?

Comment: It seems clear to me that an understanding of file size would be very relevant in a lot

Comment: ... of programming applications. (That's why I asked it; I routinely read/write large Excel files in variety of contexts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: Both formats do not differ much in regard to file size.

Binary files simply provide slightly better performance when opening or saving.

Quoting from a post written by Diego Oppenheimer on the Office Blogs:

> **File Format Number 2 – Excel Binary (XLSB files)**
>
> The Excel binary format is the second full fidelity format for Excel
>   2007.  It is similar to the Office Open XML format in structure – a set of related parts, in a zip container – except that instead of each
>   part containing XML, **each part contains binary data**.
>
> Even though we’ve done a lot of work to make sure that our XML formats
>   open quickly and efficiently, this binary format is still **more
>   efficient for Excel to open and save**, and can lead to some performance
>   improvements for workbooks that contain a lot of data, or that would
>   require a lot of XML parsing during the Open process. [...] In all other
>   respects, it is functionally equivalent to the XML file format above:
>
> - File size – **file size of both formats is approximately the same**,
>     since both formats are saved to disk using zip compression
> - Architecture – both formats use the same packaging structure, and
>     both have the same part-level structures.
> - Feature support – both formats support exactly the same feature set
> - Runtime performance – once loaded into memory, the file format has
>     no effect on application/calculation speed
> - Converters – both formats will have identical converter support

Source: [All About File Formats](https://blogs.office.com/2006/07/20/all-about-file-formats/) (Highlights added by me)

Comment: I believe you...  really I do, but why do I find @NathanielGivens' presupposition to be true then, that I generally find the .xlsb files are smaller?  I've actually never seen a case where the xlsb is larger, and it's generally significantly smaller.  Either way, thanks for the great insight -- definitely worth knowing.

Comment: There are a ton of articles advocating using .xlsb for file-size considerations, and in every other case I've found that .xlsb files are significantly smaller than their .xlsx counterparts. That's why I switched to .xlsb as my default format: for the reduction in file size.

So I was perplexed when this file ballooned in size under .xlsb and now I'm even more perplexed that this explanation says that their are nos significant differences in file size.

Comment: For an in-depth analysis, you'd have to provide your file as an example. Without knowing your file's structure, all I can think of is some issue with unused cells. At least in former versions of Excel, it decreased the file size when deleting unused rows below and unused columns to the right of your actual content.

Comment: And maybe some sort of file history or additional metadata is added to the XLSB file, if you open an existing XLSX file and save it in XLSB format. Did you check, whether copying and pasting the content of the existing XLSX file over to a *new* XLSB document makes any difference?